# Publishing third party jar to local repository in Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy

I would like to publish some third party jars to the local repository in Ivy. can you tell me how I can push the jars to the local repo?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ivy's documentation on how the `publish` Ant task works.  [The docs and a small example are here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html).  The location where the artifacts get published into depends on your ivysettings.xml.  You can obviously build your ant task around the publish to take some arguments or parameters for the 3rd party library description and pass those along to publish.